# python networkx import error: cannot import name release

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx, release

I'm on macOS, using another program needs to run python script contains networkx module. My networkx2.1 is installed using:

```
pip install networkx --user
```

The error raised is that:

```
File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/networkx/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
import networkx as nx
ImportError
from networkx import release
cannot import name release
```

I've done some search on this error, and those seem working is by using the networkx of another version, or install/uninstall.

I've already tried uninstall and reinstall networkx of version 1.9, 1.5, 1.1, however this error continues.

Anyone also encounterd this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-python/issues/192

Comment: Were there any errors from the pip install?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: I just tried installing and importing, and I have no problems.

Comment: Can you see a `release.py` or `release.pyc` file in `/Users/myname/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/networkx/`?

Comment: Also try a `pip install networkx --force-reinstall --no-deps --upgrade --user` (though if you already uninstalled it and installed older version, I doubt that'll help).

Comment: the release.py and release.pyc are in the directory.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67508158/1601580

Comment: did you try: did you try `conda install -y networkx">=2.5"`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to install networkx. please follow below steps.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-networkx

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was using MAHENDRAN BALU solution and then reinstalling:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-networkx
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall networkx
sudo python3 -m pip install networkx
```

Comment: why is your answer so complicated? how does it compare with `conda install -y networkx">=2.5"`?

Comment: Firstly, I have written my answer a few months ago, you, yesterday.
Secondly, my solution does not require conda to be installed. Moreover, that what worked for me. If you have more complaints you can find a wall and complain to it  @Charlie Parker

Answer (score 1):

The error may be due to using an older version. This worked for me:

```
pip install networkx --force-reinstall --no-deps --upgrade --user
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a specific version do:

```
conda install -y networkx">=2.5"
```

sometims `-c conda-forge` is useful (but not always recommended?)...