# Import Error: can't import name gcd from fractions

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I'm trying to import a function called gcd from a module called fractions with `from fractions import gcd`. For some reason, PyCharm throws an ImportError:

```
    from fractions import gcd
ImportError: cannot import name 'gcd' from 'fractions'
```

I had this working before, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try `conda install -y networkx">=2.5"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your traceback says Python 3.9 and [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) says
[gcd is a function in math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd)

> Changed in version 3.9: The math.gcd() function is now used to
> normalize the numerator and denominator. math.gcd() always return a
> int type. Previously, the GCD type depended on numerator and
> denominator.

Answer (score 23):

`fractions.gcd(a, b)` has been **moved to the math module in Python 3.9**. So just replace the call with `math.gcd(a, b)`.

In fact, `fractions.gcd` has been deprecated since Python 3.5 already (in brackets):

| Python Version | `fractions.gcd(a, b)` | `math.gcd(a, b)` | `math.gcd(*integers)` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Python 3.0 | X |  |  |
| Python 3.1 | X |  |  |
| Python 3.2 | X |  |  |
| Python 3.3 | X |  |  |
| Python 3.4 | X |  |  |
| Python 3.5 | (X) | X |  |
| Python 3.6 | (X) | X |  |
| Python 3.7 | (X) | X |  |
| Python 3.8 | (X) | X |  |
| Python 3.9 |  |  | X |
| Python 3.10 |  |  | X |
| Python 3.11 |  |  | X |
| Python 3.12 |  |  | X |

Additionally, `math.gcd` can take an arbitrary number of arguments (even 0 or 1) starting from Python 3.9.

Answer (score 19):

It's an issue with old networkx versions. Solve this updating networkx:

```
conda install -c conda-forge networkx=2.5
```

Comment: why do you need the `=2.5`? Why doesn't it just install the newest version on it's own? when I do `conda install -c conda-forge networkx`?

Comment: does `conda install -y networkx>=2.5` work for you - for installing at least verison 2.5?

Comment: @CharlieParker My project depends on so many ML libraries that any new library installation is probably to conflict with something (aka dependency hell). Networkx 2.5 was (at the time) the only version that worked smoothly with everything. I guess that freshly new projects might just work fine with networkx>=2.5

Answer (score 1):

if you want always at least the networkx version that works do:

```
conda install -y networkx">=2.5"
```

sometimes adding the `-c conda-forge` is useful...

Answer (score 0):

Following will install the latest version of networkx:

```
conda install -c anaconda networkx
```