# Import Error: can't import algorithms from neupy

Tags: python, neupy

I'm trying to import a library in anaconda

```
from neupy import algorithms
```

ImportError: `cannot import name 'gcd' from 'fractions'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import Error: can't import name gcd from fractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66174862/import-error-cant-import-name-gcd-from-fractions)

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a more general issue. See this previous question on the matter: [Import Error: can't import name gcd from fractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66174862/import-error-cant-import-name-gcd-from-fractions)

Answer (score 0):

From Python 3.9, GCD is moved to Math.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd

Try using `math.gcd(a, b)`.

Comment: How to try using math.gcd(a, b) in python 3.9? what do I have to do?